# How can I know that the binding of a dependency property has changed?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764916/listen-to-changes-of-dependency-property), there are at least two ways by which I can be notified that the value bound to a dependency property has changed:

1. [DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.addvaluechanged.aspx)
2. [DependencyProperty.OverrideMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.overridemetadata.aspx) on a derived class with my own PropertyChangedCallback.

This is all working fine but I need to be notified only when the actual binding is set on the property not every time the value changes. Is there a way to register a callback for this or an event I need to listen to?

I have looked in MSDN on the classes [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx), [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx), [BindingOperations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.aspx) and [DependencyPropertyDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an "official way" to do that, although I had the same problem some days ago and came up with a quite stupid but at least efficient workaround

```
private bool isSet = false;

public static readonly DependencyProperty DummyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DummySource",
                                        typeof(DummyType),
                                        typeof(WhateverYouWant),
                                        new PropertyMetadata((s, a) =>
                                        {
                                          if (!isSet)
                                          {
                                            //Blah blah about what you wanna do

                                            isSet = true
                                          }
                                        }));
```

Works fine for me, should do the trick for you as well :)

Comment: I did something similar myself but I was hoping a better solution was possible. I'll leave this question open for a few days hoping somebody knows how to do this. If nobody shows up I'll accept your answer. Thanks.