# How to subscribe to change DependencyProperty?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listen to changes of dependency property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764916/listen-to-changes-of-dependency-property)

Excuse me for my English.

I need to create a class that could subscribe to change DependencyProperty, and depending on the new value of this property to perform some action.

Like this:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.Subscribe(TextBox.TextProperty, myTextBox);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it, using the handy DependencyPropertyDescriptor class.

```
 var pd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextBox.TextProperty, typeof(TextBox));
 pd.AddValueChanged(myTextBox, OnTextChanged);


 private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: This approach causes memory leaks (see http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/propertydescriptor-addvaluechanged-alternative/)

Comment: No leaks if handler removed via RemoveValueChanged(), or if the objects live as long as the process to start with. Use judiciously.