# How to bind to ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a Visibility property on my TextBlock that I am changing via a visualstatemenager animation. I am using the objectanimationusingkeyframes object. However I also would like to bind a property in my view model to the Visibility property of my control, so that I can see when it changes and react to that. Is there a code behind way to do this?

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="commentaryStatusInfoBlock"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a [`IsVisibleChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisiblechanged.aspx) event (which does not directly correspond to `Visibility`), or you could use [generic method of listening to DP changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764916/listen-to-changes-of-dependency-property).