# WPF Intercept dependency property

Tags: wpf

I have a custom control that inherits from a datagrid.   I have to evaluate a property each time the data is bound the grid.  I am currently binding using DataSource="{Binding....}"

Is there a way that I can create a new dependency property (?) which which will be evaluated each time the DataSource property is changed?  Can I somehow "attach" my method to the DataSource Property?

I hope my intent is clear.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listen to changes of dependency property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764916/listen-to-changes-of-dependency-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to handle this by overriding OnPropertyChanged and using the following code along with my new dependencyproperty -

```
if(e.Property.Name = "DataSource")
{
// Invoke my new method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are inheriting from `DataGrid`, you can just override the `OnItemsSourceChanged` method, like this:

```
protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
{
    // update your property here
    base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
}
```

Comment: I am actually using an Infragistics datagrid, so the OnItemsSourceChanged isn't available.  I will see if there is anything similar there.