# ComboBox.SourceUpdated event is not fired

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, data-binding

I have two ComboBoxes on my view. Both of them are bound to two different `ObservableCollections` in the ViewModel, and when the selected item in ComboBox1 is changed, ComboBox2 gets updated with a different collection. The binding works just fine, however, I want the second ComboBox to always select the first item in its collection. Initially, it works, however, when the source and items in ComboBox2 get updated, the selection index gets changed to -1 (i.e. the first item is no longer selected).

To fix this, I added a `SourceUpdated` event to ComboBox2 and method that the event calls changes the index back to 0. The problem is that the method is never called (I put a breakpoint at the very top of the method and it doesn't get hit). Here's my XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource mainModel}" Orientation="Vertical">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FieldList}" DisplayMemberPath="FieldName"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>

        <ComboBox Name="cmbSelector" Margin="0,10,0,0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentSelectorList, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                  SourceUpdated="cmbSelector_SourceUpdated">
        </ComboBox>    
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
// This never gets called
private void cmbSelector_SourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbSelector.HasItems)
    {
        cmbSelector.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After working on it for an hour I finally figured it out. The answer is based on this question: [Listen to changes of dependency property.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764916/listen-to-changes-of-dependency-property)

So basically you can define a "Property Changed" event for any `DependencyProperty` on an object. This can be extremely helpful when you need to extend or add additional events to a control without having to create a new type. The basic procedure is like this:

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor descriptor = 
   DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(ComboBox));

descriptor.AddValueChanged(myComboBox, (sender, e) => 
{ 
   myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
});
```

What this does is that it creates a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` object for the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property, and then you can use that descriptor to register an event for any control of that type. In this case, every time the `ItemsSource` property of `myComboBox` is changed, the `SelectedIndex` property is set back to 0 (which means the first item in the list is selected.)

Comment: This is an old question, but for everyone who has the same problem, looking at the documentation helps: The [`SourceUpdated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.sourceupdated?view=netframework-4.8) event creates an alias for the [`Binding.SourceUpdated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.sourceupdated?view=netframework-4.8) attached event. This event is only triggered by bindings on the corresponding `FrameworkElement` with the property `NotifyOnSourceUpdated` set to `true`.