# Do propertychangedcallback's occur immediately on propertychanges?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My general understanding is that when the propertychanges, the local callback is immediately performed. So I can assume that happens immediately. However, a bound property's callback will not take place till the binding propagates, which may not occur immediately. is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds about right, though bound properties have [their own change events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7004448/546730) which are not used that often, they should occur immediately as well. The propagation is dependent on the [`Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) and may be delayed, so the binding source's event may fire later.