# Attached Event for ItemsSourceChanged on an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it possible to create an `AttachedEvent` for an `ItemsControl`, which will be fired when the `ItemsSource` or the `Items` have changed?

Something that will be used like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"
              ext:ItemsControlHelper.ItemsChanged="OnItemsChanged">
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

I think it should be possible to do this with the [`DependencyPropertyDescriptor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764916/listen-to-changes-of-dependency-property/7004448#7004448) but I just can't wrap my head around the exact implementation with an `AttachedEvent`.

Comment: your ItemsSource must be drived from INotifyCollectionChanged or INotifyPropertyChanged. Than you can easily do this.

Comment: I know I can do this in the code behind, with just adding an Event listener for NotifyPropertyChanged to the DataContext (ViewModel), but it's a not very generic solution, as I have to know what property to look out for, which means I have to look out for a hardcoded string, which can lead to propblems if the property is changed in the future. I think it's simply a cleaner solution to know as little as possible about my ViewModel.

Comment: ViewModel knowing as little as it can about the View?  Good...  View knowing as little as it can about the ViewModel?  Not really viable in MVVM.