# WPF override dependency property metdata is not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a requirement to monitor the topmost propertyvalue change on WPF Window. I am writing something like this:

```
static MainWindow()
        {
           TopmostProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(Changed)));
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static void Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

But I am getting this exception:
he invocation of the constructor on type 'WpfApplication4.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '9'."

Comment: Read the InnerException.

Comment: You wrote code that explicitly throws an exception.  Why are you surprised when it does exactly what you told it to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two mistakes:

1. The first argument of `OverrideMetadata` must be *your* type.
2. The type of the second argument must be the same as in the base type.

   ```
   TopmostProperty.OverrideMetadata(
       typeof(MainWindow),
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Changed));
   ```
3. (Bonus) You [don't need to override metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764916/listen-to-changes-of-dependency-property) if you just need change notification.

Comment: I didn't know about #2 - is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @AdiLester See [Framework Property Metadata - Specifying Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751554.aspx#Specifying_Metadata): `For existing properties (AddOwner or OverrideMetadata call), you should always override with the metadata type used by the original registration`.