# Monitor for ListView.View changes

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, dependency-properties

I want to set style from code behind for `GridView` of `ListView`. Since that is `ListView.View` dependency property, I'd like to monitor for when it is changed.

Trying to add dependency property changed callback from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7004448/1997232):

```
var handler = new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(Handler);
DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ListView.ViewProperty,
    typeof(ListView)).AddValueChanged(listView, handler);
```

where handler is

```
void Handler(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) { ... }
```

will cause compiler error:

> Error  CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler'

trying to cast `(EventHandler)handler` still keep compiler complaining:

> Error  CS0030  Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler'

---

If I try to use standard event handler:

```
var handler = new EventHandler(Handler);
```

where

```
void Handler(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
```

makes it compilable, but then it will crash at run-time with

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Handler type is not valid.

What else can I try to make `AddValueChanged` working with dependency property callback? Perhaps the approach is wrong, why? How else can I get notified when `ListView.View` is changed?

I don't want to apply either of solutions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4764946/1997232): can't use binding (value will be set in xaml) and don't want to make `MyListView` only for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DependencyPropertyDescriptor
        .FromProperty(ListView.ViewProperty, typeof(ListView))
        .AddValueChanged(listView, ViewChanged);

    listView.View = new GridView();
}

private void ViewChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("ViewChanged");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for checking, that was really helpful. The error indeed comes from another event handler (this makes my question poor), but the title + answer might be useful for someone else I guess.